# Как получить атрибуты свойства внутри его геттера(сеттера)?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Изнутри любого метода можно получить информацию о нем, в том числе атрибуты метода. Возьмем простейшую программу с классом `Cls` и кастомным атрибутом:

```
public class FullAttribute : Attribute
{
    string attr = string.Empty;
    public FullAttribute(string atr = null)
        : base()
    {
        attr = atr;
    }
}

public class Cls
{

    [FullAttribute("CustomAtttr")]
    public static void TheMethod()
    {
        var cm = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();

        var attrs = cm.GetCustomAttributes(false);

        Console.WriteLine(cm.Name + ":" + attrs.Count());
    }

    [FullAttribute("CustomAtttr")]
    public static int TheProp
    {
        get
        {
            var cm = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();

            var attrs = cm.GetCustomAttributes(false);

            Console.WriteLine(cm.Name +"+"+ attrs.Count());

            return 0;
        }


    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var r = Cls.TheProp;
        Cls.TheMethod();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Внутри `TheMethod` я получаю его имя и атрибуты без проблем. Но я не могу то же самое проделать внутри геттера свойства `TheProp`.

Свойство инкапсулирует внутри себя метод геттера. И я могу получить его с приставкой get (`get_TheProp`), но я не могу получить атрибут свойства (я знаю, что я могу назначить атрибут геттеру независимо от свойства, но мне нужно получить именно атрибут самого свойства, в котором он объявлен). Есть какой-нибудь способ это сделать?

Comment: Уберите get_ из get_TheProp и найдите такое свойство. И уже у него получайте аттрибут. Только вот зачем это делать в геттере?

Comment: @vitidev, мне тоже приходило это в голову. Но выглядит некрасиво. Думал, может, есть способ это сделать напрямую из метаданных самого геттера

Comment: Свойство это сахар. геттер - метод который сгенерил компилятор. С чего бы ему иметь аттрибуты свойства. А какая задача решается таким безумным путем?

Comment: @vitidev, допустим, это сахар. Но ведь атрибуты реальны. Они хранятся в метаданных. Да и свойства тоже доступны через рефлексию после компиляции

Comment: @vitidev, в принципе довольно сахарная задача. Хочу на этапе инициализации собрать значения из всех свойств класса в словарь

Comment: Какая то проблема XY. Один раз в конструкторе (обычном или даже статик) или даже снаружи внешним кодом собрать всю необходимую информацию о свойствах. А если нужно ловить доступ к геттерам и не хочется кодогенерации, так, раз вы уже все равно в них код пишете, просто создать словарь как поле класса и просто обращаться к нему напрямую. Нужно в геттере знание об аттрибутах? - так используем уже собранную информацию.

Comment: @vitidev, в атрибутах хранится дополнительная информация. Свойства хочу сделать умными, чтобы могли сами определять, лежат они в словаре или нет. И если нет, то автоматом себя туда добавляли + добавляли информацию из атрибутов

Comment: Понятно. Работа с рефлексией при каждом доступе - медленно и неудобно. Все-таки рекомендую 1 раз создать словарь "имя свойства - аттрибут" и использовать его из геттера, как источник аттрибутов. Никакой рефлексии в геттерах - а значит скорость работы не пострадает. Если же спортивный интерес, то, имхо, сгенеренный геттер не знает про свойство (но свойство про него знает) и поэтому достать свойство и его аттрибут нельзя никак, кроме как по имени убирая get_